# Error Installing MongoDB as a Service: Error parsing command line: unknown option -Γ

Tags: mongodb, command-line, character-encoding, windows-services

While installing MongoDB as a Windows service I got this cryptic error:

"Error parsing command line: unknown option -Γ"

The command I was using was:

"C:\inetpub\MongoDB\Local\bin\mongod.exe" --config "C:\inetpub\MongoDB\Local\Local_Mongo.conf" -–install --serviceName "LocalMongoDB" -–serviceDisplayName "LocalMongoDB"

This essentially follows the [instructions on their website](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#install-the-mongodb-service) almost exactly (while simply adding my preferred name for the service) but the error tells me next to nothing.

Answer (score 1):

After puzzling over this error I considered that the strange character might be a clue. Sure enough, I had copied this command-line from a Word document and it had converted quotations to left and right double encoded quotes (“” instead of ""). Re-typing the quotes in the command line fixed this.

Beware character encoding contamination!